# .Net System.Drawing.Image.Save with Network Credentials

Tags: .net, image

What is the best way to save an image file using System.Drawing.Image.Save with different network credentials?  My code looks like this:

```
origFrame.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(directoryName, filename))
```

However, that path is on a different domain so I want to pass some network credentials with that call, but how do I do that?

EDIT:
To further complicate the issue, the source machine is in a workgroup and the destination machine is on a domain.  I tried WNetAddConnection2 but I can't get that to work.

Comment: You can't.  Just map a drive letter to that path.

Comment: @HansPassant Huh? Wouldn't impersonating a token logged on with LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS work?